# How to return value after calling web service in Util Class using Volley?

Tags: java, android

I want to return string value after getting response from web service in Volley and call value in activity.
Below is my code;

**Utils.java**

```
    public static String getitemCountPrice(String cartId) {

    try {
        if (Utils.isNetworkAvailable(mContext)) {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put(CONSTANTS.API_param_cartid, cartId);
            params.put(CONSTANTS.API_param_token, Utils.getToken());
            JSONObject postdata = new JSONObject(params);

            try {
                YupITApplication.getJsonWithHTTPPostResponse(params, mContext, 1, (id, jsonResult) -> {
                    if (jsonResult.getString(mContext.getString(R.string.status)).equalsIgnoreCase(mContext.getString(R.string.success))) {
                        itemCountPrice = jsonResult.getJSONObject("Data").getString("Count") + ","
                                + jsonResult.getJSONObject("Data").getString("TotalPrice");
                        Log.e("itemCountPrice.............", "" + itemCountPrice);
                        // Here I get value
                    } else {
                        itemCountPrice = "0,0";
                    }
                }, Utils.cartitemcount, postdata);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, mContext.getString(R.string.no_server_found), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return itemCountPrice;
    // Here I get null and this is called before web service call
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
Utils.getitemCountPrice(cart_id));
```

Every time I get null from above method

Comment: can you post some log ?

Comment: every time I am getting null and activity's function call before service call

Comment: u need to add the line "Utils.getitemCountPrice(cart_id));" in the success call back of the volley request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your return statement will execute right after the making the API call and wouldn't wait for the response because it is written in synchronous way. You can notify the result with help of an interface

```
interface APIListener{
  public void onResponse(String itemPrice);
}
```

your method would look like this

```
    public static void getitemCountPrice(String cartId, APIListener apiListener) {

        try {
            if (Utils.isNetworkAvailable(mContext)) {
                HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put(CONSTANTS.API_param_cartid, cartId);
                params.put(CONSTANTS.API_param_token, Utils.getToken());
                JSONObject postdata = new JSONObject(params);

                try {
                    YupITApplication.getJsonWithHTTPPostResponse(params, mContext, 1, (id, jsonResult) -> {
                        if (jsonResult.getString(mContext.getString(R.string.status)).equalsIgnoreCase(mContext.getString(R.string.success))) {
                            itemCountPrice = jsonResult.getJSONObject("Data").getString("Count") + ","
                                    + jsonResult.getJSONObject("Data").getString("TotalPrice");
                            Log.e("itemCountPrice.............", "" + itemCountPrice);
    apiListener.onResponse(itemCountPrice);
                            // Here I get value
                        } else {
                            itemCountPrice = "0,0";
                            apiListener.onResponse(itemCountPrice);
                        }
                    }, Utils.cartitemcount, postdata);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, mContext.getString(R.string.no_server_found), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How can I get value after call util function

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing async call with sync call.

When you call method getItemCountPrice, you will actually receive your value from volley call when it will be available from network.
You need to use callback or some futurecall.

You can do it using callback like mentioned:

```
 public static String getitemCountPrice(String cartId, onDataListener pDataListener) {
         // some code

          YupITApplication.getJsonWithHTTPPostResponse(params, mContext, 1, (id, jsonResult) -> {
                 if (jsonResult.getString(mContext.getString(R.string.status)).equalsIgnoreCase(mContext.getString(R.string.success))) {
                        itemCountPrice = jsonResult.getJSONObject("Data").getString("Count") + ","
                                + jsonResult.getJSONObject("Data").getString("TotalPrice");
                        Log.e("itemCountPrice.............", "" + itemCountPrice);

                        // Here I get value
                  } else {
                        itemCountPrice = "0,0";
                  }

                  //pass value through callback
                  pDataListener.onItemCountPriceReceived(itemCountPrice)

                }, Utils.cartitemcount, postdata);
    // some code
}
```

Take one interface to pass data back to calling activity

```
interface OnDataListener{
    void onItemCountPriceReceived(String itemCountPrice);
}
```

YourActivity code will look like this

```
Utils.getItemCountPrice(cart_id,new OnDataListener(){
    @Override
    void onItemCountPriceReceived(String itemCountPrice){
        //you will get your value here when received from network call    
    }
})
```